# how to get private key of old receiving address in blockchain.info. I have passphrase!

Tags: blockchain

I have mistakenly sent bitcoins to my old receiving address from Unocioin wallet and later i imported it into my wallet but it is not transferring it is asking private key. neither I' m able to send to any because it is asking me private key but i didn't know where it is? i have passphrase but how can i generate private key with passphrase?

Comment: Where did you import it? Did you try to regularly log into your old Blockchain.info account?

Comment: Mine is new HD wallet. That is the problem if it is new i wouldn't have worried much... I sent bitcoins to old receiving address but blockchain changes address so i miss my old address and i don't know it's private key and i miss BTC too

Comment: have you ever found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

> Unocioin

Did you mean Unocoin.com?

As far as I can tell, Unocoin operates custodial wallets (via BitGo and Blockchain.info APIs), meaning that *only they* have access to the private keys. If this is true and you've transferred bitcoin into your Unocoin wallet, then the only way to retrieve it is to log into your Unocoin.com account (or [contact their technical support](https://www.unocoin.com/support) for assistance).

You could also try [sending a message to bitcointalk user dashingriddler](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=pm;sa=send;u=124502) who apparently is a Unocoin employee.

Comment: No sir, I bought bits in unocoin and accidentally I sent it to my old receiving address of Blockchain.info, I don't know either. So I imported my old recieving address into my wallet , it is showing as watch-only,now I can't able to transfer those funds from blockchain.info it is asking private key, I don't know where i had the private key, Mine is HD Wallet. I had passphrase but Can I recover private key from Passphrase, I've been trying from weeks about this, but I had no clue about it.

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this blog post](https://blog.blockchain.com/2015/10/27/understanding-mnemonics-and-the-blockchain-wallet/). It's from the Blockchain.info website and details how to recover your wallet using the passphrase.

Comment: Thank you for your response sir, but my problem is how to get private key of old receiving address. I didn't have the private key of that address and I don't know where it is. it is showing watch-only address.when i'm trying to import that address it's not transferring to my wallet present address, it is asking for private key. I can see the BTC in my wallet, I can see the Transaction but I can't use it. I'm stuck at present. How to get private key of Old Receiving address ?